# Silverlight DataPager custom paging

Tags: silverlight, datapager

I've looked at several examples and done google searches, and all I see the datapager doing is paging a certain number of items via the PageSize="X" property.

I would like it to page by category, is this possible?

An Example Data structure I would like to do this with would look like this.

```
ID
CategoryID
Title
Value
```

Now instead of just paging by some arbitrary number of elements, I would like it to page by CategoryID.

So the first page would be all records with CategoryID=1, and when I hit the next button on the pager, it would show all items with CategoryID=2 or whatever is next.

Is this possible?  How do I go about doing this?

Any resources or pointers would be fantastic,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataPager works with the interface IPagedCollectionView. You could create your own implementation and give it this behavior. I'm not sure how well it would work, but that is where I would start.